# Fetch / Axios crashing hard in React Native (but only for certain URLs)

Tags: axios, fetch, react-native

My app is crashing hard when doing *certain* API calls, and I narrowed it down to this point:

- it's not an HTTP vs HTTPS thing
- I eventually used two different mock APIs, and to my suprise, one worked, the other didn't. Both are basically the same, see snippet below
- same behavior on both WIFI or cellular network
- same issue in axios instead of fetch
- the `catch` block is invoked with a nondescript network error, but then the app still crashes hard

Environment: Android 10 (actual device), RN 0.61.5

Both calls below just do a simple `HTTP GET` which results in a JSON snippet being returned. One works, the other causes a hard crash.

```
async foo() {
    try {

        // this endpoint CRASHES my app
        const r = await fetch("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
        
        // this endpoint works just fine
        //const r = await fetch("http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two");

    } catch(e) {
        console.log("Invoked, but the app still crashes hard right after");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please tell the solution for the issue.

Comment: I posted my fix as an answer @TanviAgarwal -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a hint in Logcat - it appears that using OkHttp3 is causing some sort of versioning conflict that only manifests in one of the responses (maybe due to CORS headers, but that's pure, unfounded speculation ;).

My fix was to change my dependency on OkHttp3 in `build.gradle` from

```
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.7.2"
```

to

```
api(platform("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-bom:4.7.2"))
api("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp")
api("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a timeout to the config in axios

```
private axios: Axios;
private config: AxiosRequestConfig = {
    baseURL: 'http://192.168.10.18:8000/api',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    timeout: 5000
}
constructor() {
    this.axios = new Axios(this.config);
}
```

I had the same issue, axios request was crashing the application. No logs on the console or anything. Even tried resolving by the answer accepted but didn't work.

Logcat did help in understanding the issue that null was being passed in Double Data type in java. I thought maybe some animation was we were using was causing this issue, but looks like null is being passed via axios to some library like okhttp for HTTP request.