# Network Error (React-Native, Express,Nodejs,MongoDB)

Tags: node.js, react-native, express

I am getting a Network Error while calling my server(nodejs) API.

[image: Error Message and the function call.]

I have rechecked my localhost, server, and port.
They are all working fine. I have also confirmed using POSTMAN and also ran the server on the web locally to fetch data.

[image: Postman and web data]

I think I have also added the cors properly in my server.js file.

[image: server.js file]

Want some help on this.

I have also tried with dummy API and they worked fine.

My imports from front-end

[image: Imports]

Here is LogCat

[image]

[image]

Response Header in Postman

[image]

ngrok status

[image]

Comment: can you show the result of `console.log(error.response)` inside your catch?

Comment: It's giving undefined!!

Comment: @Satyam The errors returned here are probably pretty useless. If you're on Android, you might try looking at LogCat. See this post here on how to filter relevant messages: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9869609/339793

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I think you can try exposing your local host to the internet using a service like ngrok which will generate a url for you, and then try using the url to send requests instead of localhost:3000. Simply download and follow the instructions here: https://ngrok.com/docs

Comment: No problem :)))

Comment: A bit of confusion here!! How to make it permanent?                                   
Like is there any configuration to just run it on a single command(script). Now it is like running 3 ports for the same. And how to configure the generated URL?

Comment: Hi on ngrok's free plan the url generated is random and temporary. They have stated it in their documentation: https://ngrok.com/docs#getting-started-stable. Im not sure about the configuration details maybe the docs can help answer some of your questions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are having a problem in react native code, not in backend. That's why you are not getting any error in postman.

I am guessing that you are importing the dependencies is problematic way.

Comment: Thank You for your response can you just point me out particularly which dependency? I have used a dummy API and logged that on the console using Axios, which worked fine for me.

Comment: for that, you have to mention the import statement in the file. without that its difficult to tell

Comment: A common fix here is to use the actual IP address rather than `localhost`. Did you already try that?

If that's not helping: I just ran into this issue a day ago - for me, it turned out to be a versioning conflict with OkHttp3, to which I had a dependency. Would that be the case for you?

Comment: @PhilippSumi Yes, I have tried the IP address, I am getting the same error. I think I can try with OkHttp3. Can you just share a link or some info on the same. Thank You!!

Comment: @Satyam here's the link to my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62532912/339793. Maybe also try the mock APIs I posted there - maybe it helps narrowing it down.

Comment: @prisar I have added the headers. I don't know if you meant the same or something else. I am kind of new to this.

Comment: @PhilippSumi   I tried to add those api in my app **build.gradle** but still its the same. I have also uploaded the log of the same error. I didn't get that, a bit confusing.

Comment: maybe we're looking at multiple issues here. The `localhost` bit is still a bit fishy - after all, `localhost` for your device is something else then your machine (not sure how it is in an AVD). The IP address may not work if there's no listener process (for IIS for example, I have to proxy it in order to have my app talk to it when it's running locally.
Can you try accessing your API through a regular URL (e.g. through ngrok)?

Comment: @PhilippSumi  I tried that, I have posted the same. I think it's working fine 

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to use local server API in mobile application development, all you need to do is replace ***"localhost"*** in the URL with your pc ***IP address***. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using dev build in a physical device you might always noticed a local IP address in the terminal or a QR code for it.

Just replace the localhost or 127.0.0.1 with that local IP but make sure to keep the port same as your backend server.

The best answer above here is an overhead.