# Permanent solution instead of ngrok for my react-native project

Tags: node.js, react-native, express, ngrok

*I had a problem with running react-native app [Network Error] and the same is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62550990/network-error-react-native-express-nodejs-mongodb)*.

`ngrok` works for a temporary.

At the end of the day when I close my ngrok the token(link) generated is of no use. The next day if I have to run my project I have to regenerate a new token(link) and make the changes everywhere. Also, it's like running 3 ports for a single project.

Is there any solution for the same.

Thank You!!

Comment: Is that problem for both iOS and Android? Also how are you making the HTTP requests - share your code. I have been able to connect to a localhost API in the past, so it's definitely possible and ngrok is not required.

Comment: @TsvetanGanev I am running it on android. I am using Axios for HTTP requests. My code for front end and back end is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62550990/network-error-react-native-express-nodejs-mongodb). If you need it in detail I'll post it here.

Comment: I think your problem is similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55827042/8597510 - you have to whitelist localhost to allow non-HTTPS traffic from your app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after very long research I got a solution to this problem.

But for now, it only works for an android emulator. I am not sure that this will work on a physical device using ADB.

Solution....

I replaced the **http://localhost:3000** with **http://10.0.2.2:3000/**. You can also try this

```
import { Platform } from 'react-native';

export const baseUrl = Platform.OS === 'android' ?
    'http://10.0.2.2:3000/'
: 
'http://localhost:3000/';
```

This didn't work for me!!

Anyway, If there is a solution for the physical device(ADB) please I would love to know.

Thank you!!

Adios!!